# Convertir imagen CImg a cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

Estoy usando la librería CImg 2.1.3 con OpenCV 3.3.0 por lo que requiero convertir un objeto CImg a Mat, en los ejemplos de la propia libraría utilizan este código:

```
cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char> *cvImgToCImg(cv::Mat &cvImg)
{
    cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char> * result = new cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char>(cvImg.cols, cvImg.rows);

    for (int x = 0; x < cvImg.cols; ++x)
        for (int y = 0; y < cvImg.rows; ++y)
            (*result)(x, y) = cvImg.at<uchar>(y, x);

    return result;
}
```

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

¿Como puedo mejorar este código para que sea más rápido, si es posible?

Comment: ¿Has hecho pruebas de velocidad (benchmark) para determinar que este código es lento? No deberías optimizar sin motivo (consulta la [regla del 90/90](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regla_del_noventa-noventa)). En caso de que ese fragmento de código sea realmente crítico, haz lo posible por eliminar el `new` y lanza otro benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

#### Librerías implicadas.

Consultando la documentación de [The CImg Library](http://cimg.eu/), vemos que la clase `CImg` contiene un [constructor que acepta un puntero a datos](http://cimg.eu/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#a24f3b43daa4444b94a973c2c3fff82c5) junto a un ancho y alto para construir una imagen en un solo paso:

```
CImg    (   const t *const  values,
            const unsigned int  size_x,
            const unsigned int  size_y = 1,
            const unsigned int  size_z = 1,
            const unsigned int  size_c = 1,
            const bool  is_shared = false 
        )
```

El parámetro `size_x` corresponde al ancho, `size_y` al alto `size_z` a la profundidad de la imagen (sólo aplicable a [imágenes volumétricas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representaci%C3%B3n_volum%C3%A9trica)), `size_c` el número de canales.

Por otro lado, la documentación de [Open Source Computer Vision Library](https://opencv.org/) nos indica que la clase `Mat` dispone de una función para [obtener un puntero a sus datos internos](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a70ed9344cd3639e28507f81ffaac34bd):

```
uchar* cv::Mat::ptr (   int     i0 = 0  )
```

Nos advierte que debemos asegurarnos que la matriz sea continua ([todos sus elementos están almacenados de manera anexa](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aff83775c7fc1479de5f4a8c4e67fe361)) para conocer el comportamiento exacto.

#### Propuesta.

Conociendo estos datos, podemos reescribir tu función `cvImgToCImg(cv::Mat &cvImg)` de la siguiente manera:

```
//                               v <--- Devuelve una instancia, no un puntero
cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char> cvImgToCImg(const cv::Mat &cvImg)
// La matriz entrante no sera modificada ---> ^^^^^
{
    return {cvImg.ptr, cvImg.cols, cvImg.rows};
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Se construye en el punto de retorno, favoreciendo OVR
}
```

#### Mejoras aplicadas.

1. El cuerpo de la función `cvImgToCImg` ha sido simplificado para eliminar las iteraciones de los bucles y la llamada al operador paréntesis, de manera que la función trabaja menos.
2. Delega la copia de datos a mecanismos internos de la librería `CImg`, al pasar a la librería los datos a copiar directamente en lugar de asignar píxel a píxel, permitimos que la librería aplique las optimizaciones internas de que disponga (si dispone de ellas).
3. Los datos de entrada son constantes, esto puede ayudar al compilador en las decisiones de optimización pues sabiendo que una variable no contiene efectos secundarios puede tomar decisiones de optimización más agresivas.
4. El objeto resultante se construye en el punto de retorno, favoreciendo la [optimización del valor de retorno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).
5. No se usa memoria dinámica (no implicamos el operador `new`) que es más lenta.

#### Advertencia.

1. No he probado el código (así que no se si compila) pues no dispongo de las librerías que usas.
2. Las librerías internamente podrían estar alojando memoria dinámica.
3. No dispongo de benchmarks sobre los que comparar.
4. Desconozco la configuración de las imágenes que tratas, los parámetros usados para construir la `CImg` podrían no ser adecuados.
5. Asumo que las matrices recibidas serán anexas.